# Stokes theorem concept question

Tags: calculus, vector-fields, stokes-theorem

I've got a conceptual question about Stokes theorem.  So the way I understood it Stokes theorem is used to calculate the counterclockwise circulation through a smooth oriented surface.  However one of the questions at the end of the asks to find the Flux through a given surface using Stokes theorem.  I wasn't sure how this could be done, in my understanding I thought that is what Gauss's Divergence Theorem is for, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: The divergence theorem is for computing the flux through the 2D boundary of some 3D region. Stokes theorem, by contrast, is about computing the flux through some 2D surface which is bounded by some 1D curve.

Comment: How do you differentiate between finding flux and circulation using Stokes theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Stokes' Theorem gives you is the relation between the surface integral of the curl of a vector field over a smooth oriented surface S, to the line integral of the vector field over its boundary C:

$$\int_C \vec F \cdot \vec {ds} = \iint_S (\nabla \times \vec F) \cdot \vec {dS}$$

The key here is to realize that the question they're asking you, to calculate the Flux integral over the surface S using Stokes theorem can be formulated as follows:

Let  $ \vec G= \nabla \times \vec F$ then $$\iint_S \vec G \cdot \vec {dS} = \iint_S \nabla \times \vec F \cdot \vec {dS} = \int_C \vec F \cdot \vec {ds}$$ and from here what you should be able to is to find $F$ such that $G=\nabla \times \vec F$ and calculate the line integral.
(Note that this can be done if and only if $\nabla \cdot \vec G=0$ )

Hope that helps!